# Delete a record and hide it from pageBlockTable without filling the form

Tags: apex, visualforce, button, delete

I want to have a "Delete" button for every record(row) displayed on my Visualforce page, but evry time I want to delete my records I have to fill my form with some values and then the record can be deleted. If I leave my form empty and press on the ommand link "Delete Me" I get Errors like this:

[image]

I have a Controller, which looks like this:

```
public with sharing class NewStudentsControllerExtension {

    public Student__c NewStudent { get; set;}
    public List<Student__c> studenti = new List<Student__c>();
    public string studentId{ get; set; }
    public Map<Id, Student__c> studentMap { get; set; }

    public NewStudentsControllerExtension (ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){
        this.NewStudent = new Student__c();
        studenti.add(NewStudent);
        studentMap = buildStudentMap();
    }


    public Map<Id, Student__c> buildStudentMap(){

        Map<Id, Student__c> results = new Map<Id, Student__c>();

        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> studentFields = Student__c.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();

        String qry = 'SELECT ' + String.join( new List<String>( studentFields.keySet() ), ',' ) + ' FROM Student__c';

        List<Student__c> students;
        try{
            students = Database.query( qry );
        }
        catch( Exception ex ){
            System.debug( 'Error fetching students: ' + ex.getMessage() );
        }

        if( students != null && !students.isEmpty() ){
            results.putAll( students );
        }

        return results;    
    }


    public PageReference saveNewStudent(){

        try {
            insert newStudent;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.debug('Error inserting new Student: ' + ex.getMessage());
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error occurred inserting new student: ' + ex.getMessage()));
            return null;
        }

        if( newStudent.Id != null ){

            studentMap.put( newStudent.Id, newStudent );
        }

        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl());
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);

        return pageRef;
    }

    public PageReference deleteStudent() {

        Boolean hasError = true;

        if( studentMap.containsKey( studentId )){
            Student__c student = studentMap.get( studentId );

            try{
                Database.delete( student );
            }
            catch( Exception ex ){
                ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message( ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'There was a problem deleting the student: ' + ex.getMessage() ));
                return null;
            }

            hasError = false;
        }

        if( !hasError ){
            PageReference pg = Page.Aplikacija_Studenti; // your page here 
            pg.setRedirect( true );

            return pg;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is the Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page StandardController="Student__c" recordSetVar="studenti"  
extensions="NewStudentsControllerExtension">

    <h1>Vnosi in pregledi nad študenti</h1>

    <apex:form id="form">

    <apex:actionFunction name="deleteStudent" action="{!DeleteStudent}" rerender="form" >
        <apex:param name="studentId" assignTo="{!studentId}" value="" />
    </apex:actionFunction>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Vnos novih študentov">

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

                <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.ime__c }"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.priimek__c }"/>

                <apex:actionRegion > 
                    <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbToRerender">                
                        <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.tip_studija__c }" >
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="pbToRerender"/>
                        </apex:inputField>    
                            <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.Samoplacnik__c }" rendered="{! NewStudent.tip_studija__c='izredni' }">
                        </apex:inputField>          
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:actionRegion>

                <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.naziv_fakultete__c }"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.studijski_program__c }"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.letnik__c }"/>  
                <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.datum_rojstva__c }"/>  
                <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.naslov__c }"/> 

            </apex:pageBlockSection>       

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{! saveNewStudent }" value="Shrani"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{! cancel }" value="Prekliči" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageMessages />

        <apex:pageBlock title="Študenti">

            <apex:pageBlockTable id="Tabela" value="{! studenti }" var="student">
                <apex:column value="{! student.Name }"/>    
                <apex:column value="{! student.ime__c }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! student.priimek__c }"/>        
                <apex:column value="{! student.naslov__c }"/>        
                <apex:column value="{! student.datum_rojstva__c }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! student.letnik__c }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! student.tip_studija__c }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! student.naziv_fakultete__c }"/>   
                <apex:column value="{! student.studijski_program__c }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! student.Samoplacnik__c }" />  

                <apex:column >
                    <apex:commandLink onclick="deleteStudent('{!student.Id}')" value="Delete Me" reRender="Tabela"></apex:commandLink>
                </apex:column>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

So what could be the possible solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here is what you need to do:

Controller:

```
    public with sharing class StudentsControllerExtension {

        public Student__c NewStudent { get; set;}
        public List<Student__c> studenti = new List<Student__c>();
        public string studentId{ get; set; }
        public Map<Id, Student__c> studentMap     { get; set; }

        public StudentsControllerExtension (ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){
            this.NewStudent = new Student__c();
            studenti.add(NewStudent);
            studentMap = buildStudentMap();
        }


        public Map<Id, Student__c> buildStudentMap(){

            Map<Id, Student__c> results = new Map<Id, Student__c>();

            Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> studentFields = Student__c.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();

            String qry = 'SELECT ' + String.join( new List<String>( studentFields.keySet() ), ',' ) + ' FROM Student__c';

            List<Student__c> students;
            try{
                students = Database.query( qry );
            }
            catch( Exception ex ){
                System.debug( 'Error fetching students: ' + ex.getMessage() );
            }

            if( students != null && !students.isEmpty() ){
                results.putAll( students );
            }

            return results;    
        }


        public PageReference saveNewStudent(){

            try{
                insert newStudent;
            }
            catch( Exception ex ){
                System.debug( 'Error inserting new Student: ' + ex.getMessage );
                ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message( ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error occurred inserting new student: ' + ex.getMessage() );
                return null;
            }

            if( newStudent.Id != null ){

                studentMap.put( newStudent.Id, newStudent );
            }

            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl());
            pageRef.setRedirect(true);

            return pageRef;
        }


        public PageReference deleteStudent() {

            Boolean hasError = true;

            if( studentMap.containsKey( studentId )){
                Student__c student = studentMap.get( studentId );

                try{
                    Database.delete( student );
                }
                catch( Exception ex ){
                    ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message( ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'There was a problem deleting the student: ' + ex.getMessage() ));
                    return null;
                }

                hasError = false;
            }

            if( !hasError ){
                PageReference pg = Page.Test; // your page here 
                pg.setRedirect( true );

                return pg;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Page:

```
            <apex:page StandardController="Student__c" recordSetVar="studenti" 
    extensions="StudentsControllerExtension">

    <h1>Vnosi in pregledi nad študenti</h1>

    <apex:form id="form">

        <apex:pageBlock title="Vnos novih študentov">

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

                <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.ime__c }"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.priimek__c }"/>

                <apex:actionRegion > 
                    <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbToRerender">                
                        <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.tip_studija__c }" >
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="pbToRerender"/>
                        </apex:inputField>    
                            <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.Samoplacnik__c }" rendered="{! NewStudent.tip_studija__c='izredni' }">
                        </apex:inputField>   
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>       
                   </apex:actionRegion>
                    <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.naziv_fakultete__c }"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.studijski_program__c }"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.letnik__c }"/>  
                    <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.datum_rojstva__c }"/>  
                    <apex:inputField value="{! NewStudent.naslov__c }"/> 


            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{! saveNewStudent }" value="Shrani"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{! cancel }" value="Prekliči" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        </apex:pageBlock>


        <apex:pageBlock title="Študenti" >

        <apex:actionRegion >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! studenti }" var="student" id="student_list" >
                <apex:column value="{! student.Name }"/>    
                <apex:column value="{! student.ime__c }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! student.priimek__c }"/>        
                <apex:column value="{! student.naslov__c }"/>        
                <apex:column value="{! student.datum_rojstva__c }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! student.letnik__c }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! student.tip_studija__c }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! student.naziv_fakultete__c }"/>   
                <apex:column value="{! student.studijski_program__c }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! student.Samoplacnik__c }" />  

                <apex:column >
                    <apex:commandLink  value="Delete Me">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!deleteStudent}" rerender="student_list" >
                            <apex:param name="studentId" value="{!student.Id}" assignTo="{!studentId}" />
                        </apex:actionSupport>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:column> 
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:actionRegion>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageMessages />

    </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

This will effectively handle your issue with deleting selected students only. In this solution I opted to use a map of the students to handle maintaining the list of student. The main issue that I found with your original setup was 2 things.

1. Your parameter was not assigning to your selected student
2. Your delete method wasn't very efficient as it was iterating a potentially large list as this grows.

Using a map in this case makes it possible to quickly grab the record that you are removing, and the map is then rebuilt once you return your PageReference. Using the ActionSupport here along with a CommandLink helped a bit too to keep the Row with a nice look of the "Action" links you typically will see in list views. I've tested this solution and it works quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks @Ronnie, I have one more question. Now I can delete the records only if I fill my form with some values, otherwise I get page errors. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: do you have some required fields on the object level that you are having on your page? very likely those are the issue. you will need to surround your table in an action region so that anything outside is not processed in this action. Update the ActionFunction rerender param to include rerendering that region instead of the whole form.

Comment: I've updated my page section of my answer to handle within an action region for your required fields issue.

Comment: Yes I have some required fields, I also updated my page with adding action reagion like you did but the issue is the same. Could the deleteStudent function in Controller) be a problem or maybe something else?

Comment: no the issue is just the required fields.. check my update. it will work for you to resolve this. already tested it.

Comment: Another solution would have been to set `immediate="true"` on your `commandButton`. It processes the button without submitting the view state to the controller. FYI, this is why my last comment advised you to add a `pageMessages` tag, since any required field messages can get lost in the breeze if you have a lot of layers - ensuring the component & page rerenders between changes helps a lot in debugging, since you'll see the message. Nice advice anyway from Ronnie, up-voted!

Comment: The only issue i she of ever using immediate=true is if there are any preprocessing validations, they sometimes get ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Few problems here:

1. Thats not how `apex:param` works. Its very likely that your `st` variable is null. (Would have helped if you included debug statements or error messages).
2. Add a `assignTo` attribute to your `apex:param`, and a matching controller variable. Use this variable instead of the url parameter you expect.
3. Actually use the id - don't use the name. If you're deleting something from the database, it has an id. You can create a new instance of an sObject with the given id, and delete that record.
4. Remove the deleted record from your list in the controller. Otherwise it'll still show on the page.
5. Add a `reRender` to your `apex:commandButton`. Rerender your `pageBlockTable` once you delete a record. If you remove the record from the list (or query the values from the database post-delete), you'll have one less record to worry about on the page.

Controller:

```
public Id DeletedStudentId { get; set; }

public void DeleteStudent() {
    Integer index = null; 

    for(Integer i = 0; i < studenti.size(); i++) {
        if (studenti[i].Id == DeletedStudentId) {
            index = i
            break;
        }
    }

    studenti.remove(i);
    // Could move to @future if speed is an issue 
    delete new Student__c(Id = DeletedStudentId);
    // DeleteStudent(DeletedStudentId); 
}

// Happens in own, async context, does not impact user 
@future 
public static void DeleteStudent(Id studentId) {
    delete new Student__c(Id = DeletedStudentId);
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{! DeleteStudent }" rerender="PageBlockId">
   <apex:param name="studentId" value="{! student.Id }" assignTo="{!DeletedStudentId}" />
</apex:commandButton>
```

---

Personally, for deletions on pages like this, I remove the record from the list, and rerender - but defer the actual deletion to a `@future` method, with admin error reporting. Might be a bit out of scope, but I like that its faster for the end user. They don't have to wait for DML operations to run while the page rerenders, it just does.

Comment: Instead of thanking people in comments, vote on content, for example, by voting up on this question, or accepting it as the answer. See [why is voting important?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). Comments that are "noise" are usually removed.

Comment: Hmmm I cannot remove the records. When I click the "Delete" button it looks like the table refreshes a little bit but the record stays there. Do you see what is wrong?

Comment: Ill take a look when Im back in the office. In the meantime, try adding a `apex:pageMessages` tag to your page, and refresh it with the record. Any `DMLException` thrown will show a message on the page after a rerender.